# GraphQL User Authentication

Tags: mongodb, graphql

I'm trying to Query for a user and return the user only if the username and password match what's in the database. Currently if I query with the username, I get the response no matter what, doesn't matter if the password is right or wrong. (Read bottom for context) This is what my graphql schema is:

```
signInUser: {
  type: UserType,
  args: {
    username: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString) },
    password: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString) }
  },
  resolve(parent, args) {
    return User.findOne({ username: args.username }, (err, user) => {
      if (bcrypt.compareSync(args.password, user.password)) {
        return user;
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

This is my UserType schema:

```
const UserType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'User',
  fields: () => ({
    id: { type: GraphQLID },
    username: { type: GraphQLString },
    posts: {
      type: new GraphQLList(PostType),
      resolve(parent, args) {
        // Matches posts based on username
        // return _.filter(posts, { name: parent.name });
        console.log(parent.name);
        return Post.find({ name: parent.name });
      }
    }
  })
});
```

My MongoDB schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema({
  username: String,
  password: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
// model = collection in database
```

Should I be using JWT? I'm also having trouble wrapping my mind of how to handle knowing that the user has logged in on my client side of the application. I was thinking this way, if this query returned empty I could assume that the login failed, otherwise store the user id into localStorage and use it whenever. Suggestions of other approaches would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your question doesn't actually specify what your asking or what problem you're trying to resolve. I'm guessing the issue is that your response is returning null, but you should edit your question to include more details.

Comment: Hey, sorry I was actually editing the post while you responded. Sorry about that

Comment: https://www.howtographql.com/react-apollo/5-authentication/